# Is there a classification of ordered fields?

Tags: real-analysis, ordered-fields

I was reading an analysis textbook, where the author defines $\mathbb{R}$ as an ordered field with axiom of completeness, and I'm wondering why this definition is okay. (I mean why there is only one such field). I also wondered if there is a classification for ordered fields, but that's a slightly different question (I am interested in both questions )

For consistency of axioms I can prove that every ordered field must have zero characteristic, so it must contain the $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subfield. And since we have the axiom of completeness, each such field must contain $\mathbb{R}$ as a subfield, but why it can't be bigger than $\mathbb{R}$?

For classification I have no idea. I found that there are even some non-Archimedean fields as an example for ordered fields (so we have something else than just $\mathbb{R}$ and all it subfields as an example for ordered fields), but I didn't find any related work on classification even on arxiv.

Comment: On the first, no, there is no classification, there are too many of them (you can make partial distinctions, like Archimedean/non-Archimedean, complete/incomplete, real closed/not closed, etc.). Wikipedia lists some [common examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Examples_of_ordered_fields). On the second, see [Goldmakher, $\mathbb{R}$ is the only complete ordered field](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/350/RUnique.pdf).

Comment: Even more restricted classifications are open, see [Is there a complete characterization of ordered fields without definable proper subfields? on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/379302/51484) (the answer is no).

Comment: Meanwhile, any two complete ordered fields are indeed  isomorphic. *Uniquely* isomorphic even: if $A,B$ are complete ordered fields then there is exactly one isomorphism between them. The right way to approach the result is the following: $(1)$ If $F$ is an ordered field then there is a unique ordered field embedding $\eta_F$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ into $F$. $(2)$ If $F$ is a *complete* ordered field then each element of $F$ is characterized by the "rationals" less than it, that is, $$\{q\in\mathbb{Q}: \eta_F(q)<x\}=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:\eta_F(q)=y\}\iff x=y.$$ *(Note that this implies Archimedeanness.)*

Comment: Incidentally [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362991/who-first-characterized-the-real-numbers-as-the-unique-complete-ordered-field) (about the *history* of this fact) includes a proof.

Comment: Oh dear, "$\eta_F(q)\color{red}{=}y$" two comments prior should of course be "$\eta_F(q)\color{red}{<}y$." Derp.

Comment: thanks all for answers!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\Bbb R$ is a subfield of the ordered field $F,$ with the same order $<$ on both, and suppose $x\in F\setminus \Bbb R.$ Then $0<|x|\not\in \Bbb R.$

Let $r$ be the $lub$ in $\Bbb R$ of $S=\Bbb R\cap (-|x|,|x|).$ Then $r\ne |x|.$ Now

Case $(i).$ If $r>|x|$ then $\Bbb R\cap (|x|,r)=\emptyset$ because if $r'\in \Bbb R\cap (|x|,r)$ then  $r'$ would be an upper bound in $\Bbb R$ for $S$ with $r'<r$, contrary to the def'n of $r.$

Case $(ii).$ If $r<|x|$ then $ \Bbb R\cap (r,|x|)=\emptyset$ because if $r'\in \Bbb R\cap (r,|x|)$ then $r< r'\in S,$ contrary to the def'n of $r.$

In either Case, let $y=|\,(|x|-r)\,|.$ Then $y>0$. And $\Bbb R\cap (0,y)=\emptyset.$ Because if $r''\in \Bbb R\cap (0,y)$ then in Case $(i)$ we would have $r'=r-r''\in \Bbb R\cap (|x|,r),$ or in Case $(ii)$ we would have $r'=r+r''\in \Bbb R\cap (r,|x|).$

We can now show that $\Bbb R^+$ has NO $glb$ in $F.$  Suppose by contradiction that $z=glb_F(\Bbb R^+).$ Then $z>0$ because  $y$ is a positive lower bound in $F$ for $\Bbb R^+,$ so $z\ge y>0.$ But then $z<2z$ and $$\forall t\in \Bbb R^+\,(z\le t/2)\implies \forall t\in \Bbb R^+\,(2z\le t)$$ so $2z$ is a larger lower bound for $\Bbb R^+$ than $z=glb_F(\Bbb R^+),$ a contradiction.

So $F$ is not order-complete.

Comment: The main point is to find the "infinitesimal" $y$, that is $0<y$ and $y$ is a lower bound for $\Bbb R^+$ because $\Bbb R\cap (0,y)$ is empty.